# Multiple If & AND criteria in excel - formula or VBA.... either will suffice

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 2 tables.
Table 1 has the following fields:

```
1. Warehouse
2. Test Date0
3. Test Date1
4. Test Date2
```

The combination of 1,2,3 & 4 is always unique

Table 2 has the following fields:

```
1. Warehouse
2. Link No.
3. Issue date
4. [Pick test Date0] {currently blanks}
5. [Pick test Date1] {currently blanks}
6. [Pick test Date2] {currently blanks}
```

The combination of 1,2 & 3 is always unique

Need a formula to fill the blanks based on following condition:

```
    Table 1[Warehouse] = Table 2[Warehouse]
```

and

```
    Table 1[Test Date2] < Table 2[Issue Date]
```

The above criteria gives multiple results. Hence the output has to be the as follows:
First

```
    Table 1[Warehouse] = Table 2[Warehouse]
```

needs to be processed.
Post that within the subset of results received from the above, the following needs to be processed:

```
    Table 1[Test Date2] < Table 2[Issue date]
```

For this subset the following needs to be processed:

```
    min(abs(Table 1[Test Date2]-Table 2[Issue date])).
```

The record satisfying the above criteria needs to be used from Table 1 to populate the fields of Table 2.

[image: Table1]
[image: Table2]

Comment: could you please share some snaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sample data layout:

[image]

Formula in H2 is (you can drag it down/right):

```
=LOOKUP(0,0/FREQUENCY(0,($F2=$A$2:$A$28)*$G2-B$2:B$28-1)/($F2=$A$2:$A$28),B$2:B$28)
```

Frequency is often useful to find minimum distance:

```
=FREQUENCY(0,array1)
```

Returns binary array2:

```
{0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}
```

where `1` indicates the position of lowest non-negative value of array1. Array2 has one more element than array1, when all elements of array1 are negative, then the last element of array2 = 1.

In this case array1 is:

```
($F2=$A$2:$A$28)*$G2-B$2:B$28-1
```

`$G2-B$2:B$28-1` is negative for all test dates >= issue date. `($F2=$A$2:$A$28)*` part zeroes issue date for elements where warehouse doesn't match.

`LOOKUP(0,0/array2,array3)` searches for the single non-zero element of array2 and returns corresponding element of array3. The second division `/($F2=$A$2:$A$28)` is used to make sure it does not return values located outside the lookup range (letters `a`,`b`,`c` on the screenshot), when there is no match.

Comment: You are awesome and so is your solution. Thanks a ton mate. You saved me ages. :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic formula you can use, just nest the Ifs one by one

```
If A = true then
   If B = true then
      If C = True And D = True then
         'do stuff
      End If
   End If
End If
```